# access denied when trying to connect to mysql using tomcat datasource

Tags: mysql, tomcat, datasource, permissions

I'm trying to connect locally to mysql 5 server in jsp page using tomcat 6 and datasource.
I've configured everything as in the tomcat manual (web.xml, context.xml, etc.), but I get this exception:

java.net.SocketException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 127.0.0.1:3306 connect,resolve)

I checked the mysql and there is no problem with the connection itself, in fact I even succeeded connecting using direct JDBC connection (i.e. without using datasource).

Do I need to set anything in the tomcat policy file? other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, though I don't like it because I don't understand why it isn't mentioned anywhere, and why the permissions for the connector is not enough?
Can anyone explain me?

The workaround - add these lines to your tomcat policy file:

```
grant {
        permission java.net.SocketPermission "localhost:3306", "connect, resolve";
};
```