# Spring-boot + tomcat + ssh = connection link failure

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, ssh

I am trying to deploy my spring-boot application to **tomcat** (I was trying **7.0.85** and **8.5.29** version).
We are creating ssh tunnel to connect remote database , like here: [Spring Boot SSH Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526427/spring-boot-ssh-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top) (contextListener, creating ssh connection).
Everything is working perfectly when tomcat is embeded, but when I am trying to deploy I am getting **connection link failure**.
Here is my main app class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
         return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ContextListener getListener() {
        return new ContextListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(getListener());
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

 }
```

And fragments of pom.xml:

```
...   
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <main.basedir>${project.parent.basedir}</main.basedir>
</properties>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties:

```
server.contextPath=/app
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

And error is following:

```
2018-03-25 00:41:29.507 ERROR 19924 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I was reading many tutorials how to deploy war with spring-boot app to tomcat (like this https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/). I have done everything, but still getting this error.

I was trying many, many solutions, nothing helps, here are my steps:

I. Adding different properties, like:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxActive=55
spring.datasource.tomcat.maxIdle=21
spring.datasource.tomcat.minIdle=13
spring.datasource.tomcat.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=34000
spring.datasource.tomcat.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=55000
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationInterval=34000
spring.datasource.tomcat.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandoned=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.removeAbandonedTimeout=233
```

II. Using Tomcat JDBC like here and setting up connection pool: [Not able to set spring.datasource.type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833641/not-able-to-set-spring-datasource-type)

III. Checking everything, pointed in answer to this post: [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql)

IV. Changing catalina.policy to add grants, sth like here: [access denied when trying to connect to mysql using tomcat datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357094/access-denied-when-trying-to-connect-to-mysql-using-tomcat-datasource)

Currenty I restored all changes in my **server.xml** and it is looking like this:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
  <GlobalNamingResources>
      <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
   </GlobalNamingResources>
   <Service name="Catalina">
      <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
      <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
      <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
      <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
         <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
         </Realm>
         <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
         </Host>
      </Engine>
 </Service>
```

I was searching info, how to set properly ssh connection on this xml, but I haven't found anything what would help me.

What Am I doing wrong? Am I missing something? Is there any full tutorial how to deploy war to tomcat with database (or ssh)?

Comment: I bet you have to configure SSH connector there. Can you add your $CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml

Comment: Updated, as I wrote, I have no idea, how properly configure this :(